# using jquery ajax beforeSent not working for me when posting a form

Tags: jquery

Any ideas why the beforeSend does not work for me using the code below on a click event?  I guess it's the window.location but how can I handle this I don't know!?
Many thanks,

```
"use strict";

(function ($, ns, w) {

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $.post(ns.validateField, { name: userName})
            .done(function (data) {
              window.location = ns.newUrl;  // Fires browser reload
            })
            .beforeSend(function() {
              console.log("!!NOT REACHED!!");
    }) 

})(window.jQuery, namespace('wp.checkout'), window);
```

**UPDATE**

When moving the .beforeSend(..) above the .done event I get an error in firebug, shown below:

```
TypeError: $.post(...).beforeSend is not a function
.beforeSend(function() {
```

Full change detailed below

**beforeSend above done**

```
$.post(ns.validateField, { name: userName})
        .beforeSend(function() {
            console.log("HERE");  // never reached
        })
        .done(function (data) {             
            window.location = ns.newUrl;
        })
        .always(function() {
            // this is not reached as well incidentally
        });
```

Comment: What do you mean by "not working"? Can you provide more detail including information about ns?

Comment: the beforeSend is not hit when I put a tracepoint in firebug.  The window.location fires but the beforeSend never gets triggered?

Comment: `beforeSend` is not a promise interface method, but ajax option

Comment: Just for the sake of argument can you switch your .beforeSend() and .done() processes? Then test and see if the result is different? I have never seen the beforeSend() get called as the last method in the chain.

Comment: When I moved the beforeSend event before the Done the form didn't submit

Answer (score 2):

In order to use `beforeSend`, you should use [jQuery.ajax()](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) method, not the `jQuery.post()` method.
If you want to do a post request, you can specify it in settings parameters as `type:"POST"`. You should define `beforeSend` event in settings parameter too.

```
 $.ajax({
    type:"POST",
    url:"**YOUR_POST_URL**",
    data: {name:userName}
    beforeSend: function (){
      console.log("**Whatever before send!**");
    }
  });
```

Answer (score -1):

Using ajax:

```
$.ajax({
  url: "",
  data: { name: userName},
  beforeSend: function() {
    console.log("!!NOT REACHED!!")
  }
})
```

Comment: How does this answer the OP's question?